# how to remove layerd navigation on checkout page in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

I have tried to remove layered navigation on www.example.com/checkout/onepage/ by using checkout.xml using following code
 
    category_filter

But it still remains there,I want to remove it only from checkout page only are keep it on other pages.What I have to do here ???

Comment: I don't think so there is "layered navigation" on checkout page. Can you please share image? Are you talking about checkout steps navigation on right side on checkout page?

Comment: just view this link http://dustnboots-new.demoprojects99.com/checkout/onepage/

Answer (score 0):

Please check following thing:

1. in your current theme's checkout.xml search for handler `<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">` and add following line  `<remove name="left"/>`. if in current theme no checkout.xml then copy paste checkout.xml file from base theme and add it to your current theme and then do changes. Do not forget to clear cache!!
2. If option-1 is not works then right click on left side panel and check in main div what class is assigned and try to find that block name and then add
3. In worst case you can change your checkout onepage layout from 2column-left.phtml to 1column.phtml. To do create local.xml file in your layout directory and add following code and clear cache.

Thanks

Comment: for third option code is 
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate <template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>                
    </checkout_onepage_index translate="label">

Comment: as per your first step i already have this in checkout.xml    <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
        <label>One Page Checkout</label>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <remove name="left"/>

Comment: in this code there is " " is not properly ended at setTemplate can you re paste it correctly ??                                                                           <?xml version="1.0"?> <checkout_onepage_index translate="label"> <reference name="root"> <action method="setTemplate <template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> </reference> </checkout_onepage_index translate="label">

Comment: no sir, can you give me the same corrected code of 3rd solution to check is it working correctly. also for 2nd solution ....

Comment: This is the code for 3rd option: <?xml version="1.0"?> <checkout_onepage_index translate="label"> <reference name="root"> <action method="setTemplate <template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> </reference> </checkout_onepage_index translate="label">